# Android Room with RxJava Single<List<T>> compilation error

Tags: compiler-errors, rx-java2, android-room

i’m getting a compilation error 
“error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method’s return type” 
when trying to query

```
Single<List<T>> getList()
```

but when i change `Single` to `Flowable` everything is Ok.

What could be the reason for that error?

Comment: Is this a DAO method? If so, what is the purpose of List<T> - don't you know the type you will be returning based on the query?

Comment: yes DAO method. List is parametrized with specific type, let say List<MySpecificType>

Comment: Sure, but isn't the @Query annotation above this method mentioning a specific table or tables?

Comment: Can you provide the query you use in the @Query annotation? I'm using successfully `Single<List<MyType>>` so the issue must be with the query.

Comment: @Query("SELECT * FROM ActiveShooter")     
Single<List<ActiveShooter>> getAllActiveShooters();

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it provides an error, because you are observing for database changes.

Single emits and requires only **1** result. Since it's a wrapper for LiveData which notify as soon as data has been changed, it requires to use Flowable. This allows to get the data in a Stream even if there are currently no data available.

Also take care, that you should **not** use generics in classes which are generated. this may lead to unwanted behaviour.

If you really want to wrap the data into a Single you may use in your Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ActiveShooter") List<ActiveShooter> getAllActiveShooters();
```

and transform your results into a Single within your repository.

```
public void Single<List<ActiveShooter>> getActiveShooterInRepo() {
     return Single.fromCallable( () -> yourDao.getAllActiveShooters()); 
}
```

If you do that you'll loose the observability of data changes.

Comment: And now with room:RxJava2 do we need to wrap it manually, or its enough to write retern type as Single<List<ActiveShooter>> in our DAO interface? And does it different at all?